# How to assign dict values to user_id for creating objects

Tags: python

```
def insertCompany_type(request):
          if request.method == 'POST':
             try:
                data = json.loads(request.body)
                c_type = data["subject"]
                user = get_user_id(request)
                print user
                c_ty=Company_Type(user_id=user,type=c_type)
                c_ty.save(force_insert=True)
             except:
                     print 'nope'
          return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
```

`print user`

> displays [{'user_id': 1L}]

.. How can i assign 1 to `user_id` in `Company_Type(user_id=user,type=c_type)`for creating objects

Comment: What is `get_user_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user is a list of length 1, containing a dict, you can extract the value of a dict as follows:

`value = user[0]['user_id']`

You could modify your code as:

```
      if request.method == 'POST':
         try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            c_type = data["subject"]
            user = get_user_id(request)
            id = user[0]['user_id']
            c_ty=Company_Type(user_id=id,type=c_type)
            c_ty.save(force_insert=True)
         except:
                 print 'nope'
      return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
```

Also if you need to make sure the id is an integer cast it to the right data type as `int(id)`

Answer (score 1):

When you actually make a user (which doesnt happen your snippet of code) you can pass a constuctor argument setting user_id.  e.g.

```
myUser = User(name="shalin", user_id=1)
myUser.save()
```

Also, you can get user objects from requests simply by doing this:

```
user = request.user
```

which is a bit easier than what you're doing I think.

Comment: I have tried that option. It returns anonymous user. So i have retrieved the user_id matched for the token.

Comment: That just means your user isnt logged in properly.  If this is a view which only users who are logged in should be allowed to see you should decorate it with the '@login_required' Django decorator.